# Passing Events Data to jQuery week calender received from Web API as JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I am using [jQuery Week Calender](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar), Asp.net Web API as server side and Sql server as backend.

**All the work I done so far according to the demo, but the demo have static JSON data, here I need to retrieve the data from server.**

Almost all other thing are clear and working fine, but there is an problem with loadin events data from the server and passing to the calender, here is response I got from server.

```
[{"id":13,"title":"Event Name","body":"Content","start":"2012-10-16T03:30:00.00","end":"2012-10-16T06:30:00.00","typeEvnt":1},{"id":14,"title":"dfgfdg","body":"gdfgdfg","start":"2012-10-15T04:15:00.00","end":"2012-10-15T06:45:00.00","typeEvnt":1}]
```

The Date Time is in GMT format, which needed to converted into local time zone, then to add in calender.

Here is what I am doing to add it to Calender:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/api/api/event/load',
                type: 'get',
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (data) {
                        var dataString = JSON.stringify( data);   

                        callback( {events : dataString} );
});
```

But I got an error in chrome says **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined** I am quite sure this relates to Date conversion.

After this Error the Calender Doesn't load events.

Here are few point, which are not clear in mind:

1. DateTime Format in which server should send Data to the Browser.
2. How to convert it into the local time zone and pass to calender.
3. Server Side code in C#.net to be used for formating Datetime in desired format.

Over all I need the method to Retrieved DateTime Data from server and Convert it to the local time zone and then add it to jQuery Week Calender.

**Any suggestion or clue will be helpful or MVC demo.**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You are missing some close brackets in the `$.ajax` call above.

Also note that it is more common to use the `success:` setting rather than `statusCode: { 200:`...etc.

Looking at the demo on the JQuery Week Calendar site, it expects JavaScript Date objects for the start and end fields in each event.
JSON will not automatically convert these fields into a Date, so you need what is called a reviver function to do so.
You also want the text to come back in `text` format so that you can parse it using JSON parse rather than JQuery's JSON parser.

The `dateReviver` function below parses dates in ISO 8601 date format, which is what you are looking for I believe. Taken from: Courtesy of: [How to deserialize JSON text into a date type using Windows 8 JSON.parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354702/how-to-deserialize-json-text-into-a-date-type-using-windows-8-json-parse) :

```
function dateReviver(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    var re = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?)$/
    var result = re.exec(value);
    if (result) {
        return new Date(Date.UTC(+result[1], +result[2] - 1, +result[3], +result[4],+result[5], +result[6]));
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

And the ajax function calls JSON parse which in turn uses the dateReviver function to convert any date strings in there.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/api/event/load',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: text,
  success: function(data) {
      var eventArray = JSON.parse(data, dateReviver);
      callback({events: eventArray});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have no problem with ajax call its just like to give you idea, I pasted some code above just to give an overview how data is coming.

Main problem is to make the date in correct format and supply to Week Calender.

Comment: @ishan-dhingra Edited answer in response to your comment

Comment: @IshanDhingra Did this answer your question? Do you need any more information?

Comment: @mcccanf this helped me to make things work on Chrome. for other it still going on, its an big project, will let you if I got stuck any where.