# jQuery weekcalendar: cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using [jQuery Weekcalendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) and instead of statical data, I want to use data from my database. The script below creates the `eventData1` variable that contains all appointments for the calendar. When I paste the output from below by hand, everything works fine. When I add it via variable, it crashes with this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined
```

So I think it is not able to convert the dates into new Date objects. That's why I tried to use a seperate function that should convert the string to a date, but without success.

```
events : [{'id': 25, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-07 14:45:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-07 15:45:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0},{'id': 26, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-10 11:15:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-10 12:15:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0},{'id': 22, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-09 12:45:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-09 14:45:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0},{'id': 21, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-09 15:00:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-09 17:00:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0},{'id': 20, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-08 16:00:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-08 17:00:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0},{'id': 27, 'start': new Date( '2013-01-10 15:45:00'), 'end': new Date('2013-01-10 16:45:00'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0}]
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function dateReviver(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
          var re = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/
          var result = re.exec(value);
          if (result) {
              return new Date(Date.UTC(+result[1], +result[2] - 1, +result[3], +result[4],+result[5], +result[6]));
          }
        }
        return value;
      }

      var appointments = "[";
      var eventData1 = new Array();
      var counter = 0;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.slinder.ch/admin/php/termin_getappointments.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {

            console.log('entered getJSON()');
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(i, appointment) {
                var id = appointment.appointmentId;
                var start = appointment.start;
                var end = appointment.end;
                var title = appointment.prename;
                var userid = appointment.workerid;

                appointments += "{'id': " + id + ", 'start': new Date( '" + start + "'), 'end': new Date('" + end + "'), 'title': 'test appointment from javascript', userId: 0}";

                console.log(start);
                console.log(end);

                if (i === (data.length - 1)) {
                    // this is the last                    
                } else {
                    appointments += ",";
                }             
                counter++;
            });

            appointments += "]";
            console.log('first: ' + appointments);

            eventData1 = {
                options: {
                  timeslotsPerHour: 4,
                  timeslotHeight: 20,
                  defaultFreeBusy: {free: true}
                },
                events : appointments,

                freebusys: []
            };
        }
  });

  </script>
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to change in order to use my appointments like this:

```
events : appointments,
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903342/passing-events-data-to-jquery-week-calender-received-from-web-api-as-json) on SO, but also without approved answer.

Comment: why are you building JSON via string concatenation? just build an object and use `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a string in the `appointments` variable. Therefore, it cannot be used as an array. Instead, build a normal JavaScript array with objects.

```
var appointments = [];
....
appointments.push({
    id: id,
    start: new Date(start),
    end: new Date(end), 
    title: 'test appointment from javascript', 
    userId: 0
});
...
```

EDIT:

Or you can simply push the data that you've got from the server, since it doesn't look like you're actually modifying it. If you're simply renaming the keys, It's probably not worth the extra effort.